# Lazy loading angular modules but not using the route prefix

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an app where I'm lazy loading a module called `lazy`. That module is lazy loaded via this:

```
{
  path:'lazy',
  loadChildren: 
  './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
}
```

The `lazy` module has the following routes in it:

```
const routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: LazyComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'faq',
   component: FaqComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'details',
   component: DetailsComponent
 },
]
```

The above works fine but I can only access the routes of my lazy loaded module via `/lazy/faq` or `/lazy/details`. But what I really want is to not use the route prefix `lazy` and access the routes of my lazy loaded module directly via `/faq` and `/details`.

Is this possible to do? I have not been able find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The url of components within lazy loaded modules is a combination of the url to the module e.b 'lazy'-> LazyLoadedModule plus the relative path within that module e.g 'faq->FaqComponent.

So the url is `path/to/lazy-module + 'relative/path'`. In your case `lazy/faq`. You cannot omit the prefix.

What you can do is to add a redirect in your routing config:

```
path: 'faq',
pathMatch: 'full,
redirectTo: 'lazy/faq'
```

When you use routing within your lazy module you can use relative routes: `this.router.navigate(['faq'])` but the url in the browser would be `lazy/faq` though.

Another option would be to use empty route for loading your module:

```
path:'',
loadChildren: ...
```

But that would load your module immediately when your application starts.